# How to return each iteration using for loop in Django views

Tags: python, django, database, django-views

How to print all the for loop iteration in template

**models**

[image: This is my model]

**views**

[image]

Comment: Please post a code fragment, not an image of that code fragment. Furthermore explain your problem with clear input/output. Finally share relevant models.

Comment: This is my Views                                                                                              
  def View_Client(request):
    form = Client.objects.all()
    for i in range(len(form)):
        obj = Client.objects.filter(Name=form[i])
        print(obj)
        object = Client.objects.filter(Name=form[i]).values('id')
        print(object)
        cp_obj = Client_Process.objects.filter(client_id__in=object)
        print(cp_obj)
    return render(request, 'client_list.html', {'form' : form, 'cp_obj' : cp_obj})

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `id`, Django is really good at letting write simple, readable code. Assuming `Client_Process` has a `ForeignKey` to `Client` (i.e. one `Client` can have many `Client_Process`'s:

In your view:

```
def view_client(request):
    clients = Client.objects.all().prefetch_related('client_process_set')
    return render(request, 'client_list.html', {'clients': clients})
```

In your client_list.html:

```
{% for client in clients %}
   {{ client.name }}
   Client processes:
   {% for process in client.client_process_set.all %}
        {{ process.name }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, and I got a new error like         Cannot find 'Client_Process' on Client object, 'Client_Process' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Comment: It’s “client_process” not “Client_Process”. Django lookups use the lowercase of the model class name.

Comment: I got same error Cannot find 'client_process' on Client object, 'client_process' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Comment: I have 3 models, Please refer my model in Question, I updated

Comment: Please don’t use screenshots. Coot&paste your code and format it as code.

Comment: try 'client_process_set'. Normally you should use CamelCase for your class names, not a mix of CamelCase and snake_case. It should be `ClientProcess` not `Client_Process`, that's confusing. Also `ViewClient` not `View_Client`. That's breaking python conventions (PEP8).